# NUCLEO-H743ZI2 connected to the port showing that is connected on device manager but in STM32CubeIDE not connected ( STLINK )

Tags: stm32, nucleo

I am using a NUCLEO-H743ZI2 and when I connect it to the port it lights up a led red (LD4) and it says in STM32CubeIDE: NO ST-LINK detected! but in the device manager, it is there.
[image]

Comment: Do you have any other program operate with ST-Link? If you have cubeprogrammer connected to ST-Link, for example, it blocks access for other software

Comment: restart the computer :)

Comment: The cable was interrupted and when I updated the firmware for ST-LINK something went wrong but didn't tell me that, I updated the firmware again with a suitable cable and now it works fine. Thank you for your suggestions :D

Answer (score 0):

Cause :
When you do write program, you make miss Clock setting.

How to slove it :

1. Run STM32CubeProgrammer.
2. Change "Mode" into "Power down"
3. Connect
4. Erase full chip flash memory.

Before you make programing in to you board,
Please Check Clock setting again.
If you won't change, it will happen again.

Happy programming.